# Is there a way to fork Java VMs with Maven Failsafe plugin. I am using Junit with Serenity Runner

Tags: java, maven, junit, serenity-bdd, leanft

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.idexx</groupId>
    <artifactId>qe-lynxx-automation</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <properties>
        <serenity.version>2.0.27</serenity.version>
        <lean.ft.version>14.50.0</lean.ft.version>
        <test.directory>${project.build.testSourceDirectory}/tests</test.directory>
        <tags></tags>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
```

1. I have all the required dependencies but not including here.
2. I am unable to run test parallelly with forkCount or  methods. It works fine would the sureFire plugin but I cannot use the surefire plugin to generate serenity reports.
3. I have tried a combination of forkCount and parallel that didn't work either.
4. I was able to fork multiple Java VMs using the sureFire.
5. I am trying to run test parallelly in multiple virtual machines. Our application is swing based java application and we are using LeanFt to automate the testing process.

   ```
   <build>
       <plugins>
               <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
               <configuration>
               <forkCount>2</forkCount>
               <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>

                   <includes>
                       <!-- Run every java class in the 'tests' package -->
                       <include>${test.directory}/*.java</include>
                   </includes>

                   <systemPropertyVariables>
                       <tags>${tags}</tags>
                   </systemPropertyVariables>
               </configuration>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>integration-test</goal>
                           <goal>verify</goal>
                       </goals>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
           </plugin>

           <plugin>
               <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>${serenity.version}</version>

               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <id>serenity-reports</id>
                       <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>aggregate</goal>
                       </goals>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
           </plugin>

           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.6.1</version>
               <configuration>
                   <source>1.8</source>
                   <target>1.8</target>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>


       </plugins>
   </build>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how it actually works. All you have to do is add Surefire plugin with Failsafe plugin when you use both of them. It works like a charm.

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>false</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <!-- Run every java class in the 'tests' package -->
                    <include>${test.directory}/*.java</include>
                </includes>

            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.maven.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <tags>${tags}</tags>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>serenity-reports</id>enter code here
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>aggregate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```